# Subfolder in Controllers ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my Controllers folder i want to have a subfolder called Admin.

[image]

When i go to http://localhost:port/Admin/Login/ it says the page could not be found.

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ICT4Events
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a routing issue. There is a decent intro to routing here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs If you can provide what is inside your route.config file, I may be able to help some more

Comment: Routing is controlled by [added routes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), not by folder structure.

Comment: Also, if using MVC 5, you could have a crack at attribute routing. I much prefer it to the conventional way http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: Do you have a corresponding "Admin" folder in "Views" directory?

Comment: @DavidWatts see post

Comment: I recommend areas as an alternative as well. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the next route to handle your issue:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AdminSubForder",
                url: "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

DON'T FORGET to change default value for `controller = "Home"` to controller where you want to redirect when user types `http://localhost:port/Admin/`.

So when you go to  `http://localhost:port/Admin/Login/` you will use `Login` controller and `Index` action in the Admin folder.

**IMPORTANT**
Also put this route BEFORE default route, because if you put this code after your "Default" route ASP.NET will read your `http://localhost:port/Admin/Login/` like URL with `Admin` controller and `Login` action.

Answer (score 2):

Your new route "SubFolder" does not include the possibility of including an action in the route (in your case, "Admin").

Your url wants to match routie like

```
"SubFolder/ChildController/{action}"
```

If don't include the "{action}" in your route,  it won't match your route. It then tries the default route, which obviously fails.

Try adding "{action}" to your route as shown in the below example

```
routes.MapRoute(
"SubFolder", // Route name
"SubFolder/ChildController/{action}",
new { controller = "ChildController", action = "Index" },
new[] { "Homa.Areas.Kiosk.Controllers.SubFolder" });
```

Comment: I need to add like 5 Maproutes for 5 different controllers?

Comment: One route is enough for all the five controllers. Routing is just pattern matching mechanism. The route values for controller and action specified in the example code posted by me is default route. If you dont give values for controller or action then default route will fire.