# RouteConfig.cs doesn't work as expected for Subfolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created an Admin subfolder to contain all of my admin related controllers. Similar to this one: [Subfolder in Controllers ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802430/subfolder-in-controllers-asp-net-mvc)

Here are my codes in `RouteConfig.cs"

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Admin",
            url: "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        );
```

I have a `ManageUserController` under the `Admin` folder, and `Admin` is under the `Controllers` folder.

I have a `PublicContollers` directly under the `Controllers`

Below are my problems:

1. All of my `Html.ActionLink` or `Return View()` and any other similar Redicrecting are getting confused. For example, `Html.ActionLink("Public", "Index", "Public")` would take me to `www.something.com/admin/public/index`instead of just `www.something.com/public/index`
2. It really doesn't seem like the `admin` keyword is doing any use in the routing. For example, both `www.something.com/admin/manageUser/index` and `www.something.com/manageUser/index` would take me to the same place.

Expected output:

1. If I have `Html.ActionLink("Public", "Index", "Public")`, it should take me to `www.something.com/public/index`, similarly, if I have `Html.ActionLink("Manage Users", "Index", "ManageUser")`, it should take me to `www.something.com/admin/ManageUser/index`
2. If I type in `www.something.com/ManageUser/Index`, it should throw me page not found error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Subfolders aren't officially supported by MVC. The answer to the linked question shows how to mimic *one* subfolder. If you wanted to create nested subfolders, you would need a new route for each of them, and each level could only support a single controller.

If you really want your MVC application to behave like it has subfolders, I would suggest using [MvcCodeRouting](https://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/), which configures MVC routing dynamically by the namespace the controllers are in (which if using Visual Studio, will be the same hierarchy as the subfolders), and will support multiple controllers in each folder.